# NotifyAll/SignalAll makes thread stop working properly

Tags: java, concurrency

I am trying to make a little database that is able to authenticate users, it is stored in my Server and the pointer to it is stored in each thread, making it the same for all Threads on the Server.
To register a user I user a function that uses await and signalAll, but the code "stops" at signalAlland nothing more is done.

I tried to change the await and signalAll to the conditions equivalent wait and notifyAll and nothing, also tried changing signalAll to signal and it still hangs there.

```
public void registerUser(String email,String password){
    while(!canLogin){
        try{
            loginCondition.await();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }
    canLogin=false;
    this.userlist.put(email,new User(email,password));//This runs since I can login with the account after restarting the client
    canLogin=true;
    //System.out.pritnln("Starting Signal"); <----- This runs
    loginCondition.signalAll(); //Stops working here
    //System.out.pritnln("After Signal"); <----- This doesn't
}
```

Because of this, no thread wakes up after it if they are waiting.

EDIT: As @Slaw said, I forgot to declare the method as synchronized.

Comment: You are just notifying others waiting threads that something happened inside the current one, you are not unlocking anything as I can see from a code.

Comment: if I type more commands they don't work. they only start working after I restart the client (if I type /login, for example, it doesn't give me an output.

Comment: Does the thread own the `Lock` that the `Condition` belongs to? Are you swallowing any exceptions anywhere (e.g. an `IllegalMonitorStateException`)? In your `while` loop you catch `Exception` and do nothing with it so for all you know the code could be trying to `await` and throwing an exception over and over. However, any possible exception thrown by `signalAll` will be thrown out to the caller of `registerUser`.

Comment: @Slaw From his code loginCondition owns a dead lock. Ash, please, carefully read my first comment.

Comment: @MS90 The call to `registerUser` might be surrounded by `lock`-`unlock` code.

Comment: I highly doubt about it, but it's possible( my advice would be to deal with it within a method however ). Lets hear his response. @Slaw

Comment: No, the lock is own by everyone, and there is no lock() nor unlock() in the other function @slaw .

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant @ms90

Comment: See [`ReentrantLock.newCondition`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#newCondition()) documentation. The thread must own the lock before it can call the awaiting/signalling methods of the `Condition`. This behavior is similar to the `Object` wait/notify methods which must be used from within a `synchronized` block.

Comment: Forgot the synchronized. It worked, thanks a lot!